# When is $(12x+5)/(12y+2)$ not in lowest terms?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I am struggling to solve this problem and would appreciate any help:

> When is $\frac{12x+5}{12y+2}$ NOT in lowest terms? ($x$,$y$ are nonnegative integers)

I have found that it is not in lowest terms for $x=6$ and $y=9$ because numerator and denominator are divisible by $11$, but I'm stuck here.

---

**EDIT**: Apparently "lowest terms" isn't in common usage in maths, so I will have to explain what it means. A fraction $p/q$ with $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q\ne 0$ is in *lowest terms* when $\gcd(p,q)=1$. Otherwise, it is not in lowest terms.

For example, $\frac{3}{5}$ and $\frac{9}{2}$ are in lowest terms, but $\frac{15}{3}$ and $\frac{17}{34}$ are not.

Comment: Yeah, $\frac{17}{34}$ is a good example.

Comment: For another example where it's not in its lowest terms have $x=5$, $y=2$  then numerator and denominator are divisible by 13

Comment: Do you know if the question has a simple answer? There are a lot of solutions, but no pattern is evident.

Comment: Judging from the several deleted answers below, there is probably no simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

### When is $\dfrac{12x+5}{12y+2} $ irreducible?

This is really just a partial answer.

So, when does $12x + 5 = A$ and $12y + 2 = B$ where $\gcd(A, B)=1$

Note that

\begin{align}
   12 &\mid 2A - 5B \\
   5B &\equiv 2A \pmod{12} \\
   B &\equiv 10A \pmod{12} \\
   B &= 12n + 10A
\end{align}

So $\gcd(A,B)=1$ becomes $\gcd(12n, A) = 1$.

\begin{align}
   12y + 2 &= B \\
   12y + 2 &= 12n + 10A \\
   12y &= 12n + 10A - 2 \\
\hline
   10A &\equiv 2 \pmod{12} \\
   5A &\equiv 1 \pmod 6 \\
    A &\equiv - 1 \pmod 6 \\
    A &= 6\alpha - 1 \\
\hline 
   12y &= 12n + 10(6\alpha - 1) - 2 \\
   12y &= 12n + 60\alpha - 12 \\
   y &= n + 5\alpha - 1 \\
\hline
   B &= 12n + 60\alpha - 10
\end{align}

Finally, we solve for $\alpha$.

\begin{align}
   12x + 5 &= A \\
   12x &= 6\alpha - 6 \\
    2x &= \alpha - 1 \\
  \alpha &= 2x + 1
\end{align}

---

Pick any integer value for $x$.

$ \alpha = 2x + 1 $

$ A = 12x + 5 $

Pick any $n$ such that $\gcd(12n, A) = 1$.

$B = 12n + 10A$

$y = n + 10x + 4$ implies

$$ \dfrac{12x+5}{12y+2} = \dfrac{12x+5}{12n + 120x + 50}$$

which is irreducible as long as $\gcd(12n, 12x+5) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Fractions in general are in lowest terms $6/\pi^2$ of the time.
One quarter of fractions can cancel 2, one ninth can cancel 3, and so on, so the proportion with no prime factor to cancel is $$\frac34\cdot\frac89\cdot\frac{24}{25}\cdot\frac{48}{49}\cdots=\frac6{\pi^2}$$
For these fractions, $2$ and $3$ will never cancel, so we lose the factors of $3/4$ and $8/9$ from the left-hand side.
These fractions are in lowest terms this proportion of the time:
$$\frac43\frac98\frac6{\pi^2}=\frac9{\pi^2}\approx 0.91189$$